# Fancyhdr Chapter/Section not updating correctly

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a fairly complex document. The `fancyhdr` package is used to format the header and footer. Since I need multiple styles, I defined three different styles:

```
\fancypagestyle{default}{
\fancyhf{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{page_only}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header fields
    \lfoot[\thepage]{}
    \rfoot[]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header fields    \lfoot[\thepage]{}
    \rfoot[]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%Redefine chapter by adding fancy as the chapter title page page-style
\makeatletter
    \let\stdchapter\chapter
    \renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
    \newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
        \stdchapter*{#1}
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
    }
    \def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
        \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
        \thispagestyle{default}
    }
\makeatother
```

In general, all styles are accessible. However, if I use the `default` style, the chapter and section names are not updated. I have no idea, why this is happening.

Here is a full listing of the preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{extreport}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % direct input of unicode chars like äöüß
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem, binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{6pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 0pt\raggedright}%
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-16pt}{16pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
%\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-16pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font={small,it}]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
% Einrückung für Quellcode
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{.5em}
\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage[
%    showframe=true, %Margins visualisieren
% papersize={17cm,24cm},
  paperheight=24cm,
  paperwidth=17cm,
    lmargin=20mm, %Margin left
    rmargin=18mm, %Margin right
    tmargin=30mm, %Margin top
    bmargin=25mm, %Margin bottom
    headsep=10mm
    %    marginparwidth=1cm, %Notizrand rechts
%    marginparsep=0.5cm,
%    paper=a5paper,
%    includehead, % Kopfzeile in Berechnung einbeziehen
%    includemp % Marginpar in die Berechnung mit einbeziehen
]{geometry}


% Print frame around page components
%\usepackage{showframe}


\fancypagestyle{default}{
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header fields
  \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
  \lfoot[\thepage]{}
  \rfoot[]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{page_only}{
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header fields
  \lfoot[\thepage]{}
  \rfoot[]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header fields  \lfoot[\thepage]{}
  \rfoot[]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


%Redefine chapter by adding fancy as the chapter title page page-style
\makeatletter
    \let\stdchapter\chapter
    \renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
    \newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
        \stdchapter*{#1}
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
    }
    \def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
        \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
        \thispagestyle{default}
    }
\makeatother



\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\hyphenation{na-no-crys-tal-lo-gra-phy indexmajiq}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newenvironment{abstractpage}
  {\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {\vfill\cleardoublepage}
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1]
  {\bigskip\selectlanguage{#1}%
   \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}
  {\par\bigskip}

\usepackage{setspace}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a compilable version, stripped to the minimum, of your document, not too fragments nobody can compile out of the box. I am not sure that using **both** `titlesec` **and** `fancyhdr` is a good approach

Comment: Did you issue the command `\pagestyle{default}`? When I add a small body to your preamble, with `\pagestyle{default}` and a couple of chapters and sections I do get these in the header, but not (of course) without that `\pagestyle` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I found out that the 'empty' style can not be overwritten using `fancypagestyle`. So renamed the template to `custom_empty` and everything is working now.